# How do I delete a class on load?

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever my page loads, I try to remove a class from an element, but it still stays there.

I've tried using `.removeclass()` and `remove()` and `getElementById()` and `removeChild()`.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("#logo");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

```html
<a class="logo" href="/brand/logo.svg"></a>
```

The class is still being displayed after the change.

Comment: `elem.classList.remove(className)`

Comment: `Element.className = undefined;` if it's just a single class. By the way wrong way to `document.getElementById`. Leave off `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to access the element by the id `#logo`. You don't include the `#` when using `getElementById`, and simply use `logo`. Also you were trying to remove the element, not the class. You have to use `ELEMENT.classList.remove("CLASS_NAME");`

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("logo");
elem.parentNode.classList.remove("logo");
```

```html
<a class="logo" href="/brand/logo.svg"></a>
```